# CRUD operations for Table Storage from Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I have a small problem. I am trying to do a migration from Cosmos db to table storage in Azure. The problem is that I haven't dealt with table storage for a long time. It turned out that a large part of the packages that I used before were already out of date. And the offical documentation does not provide the needed information.

Currently I use this method to add item :

```
public static async Task AddDomain(CloudTable table, DomainEntity domain)
        {
            TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert((Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.ITableEntity)domain);

            await table.ExecuteAsync(insertOperation);
        }
```

and this function App to add Domain:

```
[FunctionName("AddDomain")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function,"post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            [Table("Domains")] CloudTable domainsTable,
            ILogger log)
        {
            DomainEntity domain = CreateDomain();
            await AddDomain(domainsTable, domain);
            return new OkResult();
        }
```

But when i run the function its throw Exception :

```
Error indexing method 'AddDomain'
```

and

```
System.InvalidOperationException at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Tables.TableAttributeBindingProvider.TryCreate.
```

I have same problems with other CRUD operations too. Any idea what is going on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how i did it last month

My service class

```
using Azure;
using Azure.Data.Tables;
using VPMS.FuncApp.EFCore.AuditSetup;

namespace VPMS.Persistence.AuditSetup;

internal class TableStorageService : ITableStorageService
{
    private readonly TableServiceClient _tableServiceClient;

    public TableStorageService(TableServiceClient tableServiceClient)
    {
        _tableServiceClient = tableServiceClient;
    }

    public async Task BulkInsert(string tableName, string partionKey, List<AuditTableStorageTable> audit)
    {
        var client = _tableServiceClient.GetTableClient(tableName);

        List<TableTransactionAction> addEntitiesBatch = new List<TableTransactionAction>();

        addEntitiesBatch.AddRange(audit.Select(e => new TableTransactionAction(TableTransactionActionType.Add, e)));

        await client.SubmitTransactionAsync(addEntitiesBatch).ConfigureAwait(false);

    }

    public async Task CreateTableIfNotExistsAsync(string tableName)
    {
        var client = _tableServiceClient.GetTableClient(tableName);

        await client.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
    }
}
```

My Function App

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using VPMS.FuncApp.EFCore;
using VPMS.FuncApp.EFCore.AuditSetup;
using VPMS.Persistence.AuditSetup;

namespace VPMS.FuncApp.ArchiveAppAuditLogs;

public sealed class ArchiveAppAuditLogTimerTrigger
{
    private readonly VPMSDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly ITableStorageService _tableStorageService;

    public ArchiveAppAuditLogTimerTrigger(VPMSDbContext dbContext, ITableStorageService tableStorageService)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _tableStorageService = tableStorageService;
    }

    [FunctionName(nameof(ArchiveAppAuditLogTimerTrigger))]
    public async Task ArchiveAppAuditLogTrigger([TimerTrigger("%ArchiveAppAuditLogCron%")] TimerInfo myTimer)
    {
        var currentDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Date;

        var auditTable = _dbContext.Set<Audit>();

        await _tableStorageService.CreateTableIfNotExistsAsync(FuncAppConstants.AuditTableName);

        var query = auditTable.Where(w => w.CreatedOn < currentDate);

        int pageSize = 100;
        bool hasMoreRecords = true;

        for (int skip = 1; hasMoreRecords is true; skip++)
        {
            var recordsToSync = await query.Skip(0)
                                           .Take(pageSize)
                                           .ToListAsync();

            hasMoreRecords = recordsToSync.Any();

            if (hasMoreRecords is false) break;

            var groupedAuditData = recordsToSync.GroupBy(b => b.TableName).ToList();

            foreach (var groupedAuditDatem in groupedAuditData)
            {
                List<AuditTableStorageTable> auditStorageTableRecords = new();

                foreach (var auditEntry in groupedAuditDatem.ToList()) auditStorageTableRecords.Add(AuditTableStorageTable.BuilData(auditEntry));

                await _tableStorageService.BulkInsert(FuncAppConstants.AuditTableName, groupedAuditDatem.Key, auditStorageTableRecords);

            }

            auditTable.RemoveRange(recordsToSync);
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

    }
}
```

My Azure function app startup class

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Azure;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;
using VPMS.FuncApp.EFCore;
using VPMS.FuncApp.Interfaces;
using VPMS.FuncApp.Services;
using VPMS.Persistence.AuditSetup;
using VPMS.SharedKernel.Interfaces;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(VPMS.FuncApp.Startup))]

namespace VPMS.FuncApp;

public sealed class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var configurations = builder.GetContext().Configuration;

           
        builder.Services.AddAzureClients(builder =>
        {
            builder.AddTableServiceClient(configurations.GetValue<string>("AzureWebJobsStorage"));

            builder.UseCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential());
        });
    }
}
```

The class the TableStorage inherits from

```
using Azure;
using Azure.Data.Tables;
using VPMS.Persistence.AuditSetup;

namespace VPMS.FuncApp.EFCore.AuditSetup;

public sealed class AuditTableStorageTable : ITableEntity
{
    public string? UserId { get; set; }
    public AuditType AuditType { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; } = null!;
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string? OldValues { get; set; }
    public string? NewValues { get; set; }
    public string? AffectedColumns { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryKey { get; set; } = null!;
    public Guid BatchId { get; set; }

// these comes from the implemented interface

    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? Timestamp { get; set; }
    public ETag ETag { get; set; }

    public static AuditTableStorageTable BuilData(Audit audit)
    {
        return new()
        {
            PartitionKey = audit.TableName,
            TableName = audit.TableName,
            AffectedColumns = audit.AffectedColumns,
            AuditType = audit.AuditType,
            BatchId = audit.BatchId,
            CreatedOn = audit.CreatedOn,
            OldValues = audit.OldValues,
            NewValues = audit.NewValues,
            PrimaryKey = audit.PrimaryKey,
            RowKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            UserId = audit.UserId,
        };
    }
}
```